# String substitution on array of strings

Tags: arrays, json, jq, edit

I am trying to strip a substring from an array of strings; this array is obtained as a key set from a map. Some example incoming data:

```
{
  "appOneVersion": "1.0",
  "appTwoVersion": "1.0",
  "appThreeVersion": "1.0"
}
```

First I'm extracting the key set and making lower case which works:

```
 $ jq -r 'with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase) | keys' example.json
[
  "apponeversion",
  "appthreeversion",
  "apptwoversion"
]
```

and then I'm attempting to strip the `version` part of each element with `sub("version$"; "")` however I'm not quite understanding how to make it iterate over the array instead of `sub` trying to operate on the array as a whole:

```
$ jq -r 'with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase) | keys | sub("version$"; "")' example.json
jq: error (at example.json:5): array (["apponever...) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

Comment: I am trying to get all the keys; @peak below gave some options that work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `map` would do the trick, and you might also consider `keys_unsorted`:

```
with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase )
| keys_unsorted | map(sub("version$"; ""))
```

Of course, there are other approaches....

If you wanted to retain the original structure:

```
with_entries( .key |= (ascii_downcase | sub("version$";"")))
```

Comment: Thanks, the original structure is not important so either will be fine. As with `jq` there probably are other approaches but this looks good for me.